# Triggering text-to-speech Teams outbound call via Microsoft PowerAutomate

Tags: twilio, microsoft-teams, text-to-speech, power-automate, azure-cognitive-services

I have a dynamically created text which I need to be "translated" into speech (via Azure Cognitive service or a different one, whatever works) and a specific number being called. If someone picks up, they should confirm by pressing # or whatever, if they do not pick up or voicemail is on, the call should end and a different phone number should be called.

I want to build all this via a Microsoft PowerAutomate flow.

Is this possible with PowerAutomate and Teams or do I need external tools such as Twilio?

The out of the box Teams connector does not seem to allow automated outbound calls: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/teams/#actions

I also checked the Twilio connector in PowerAutomate and it only supports sending SMS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/twilio/#actions

Comment: Triggering text-to-speech for Teams outbound call doesn't seem to be feasible using Power Automate.

Comment: Thank you @Prasad-MSFT - but why not? :) Does Teams generally does not offer this functionality? If there are no OOB connectors, I could still build it via API calls, no?

Comment: Please refer these docs which might help: 1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/dial-voice-reference  2. https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/tree/main/articles/cognitive-services/Speech-Service